# Jquery: How to sort SVG g element by translate filter value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Do you know how to sort SVG group elements by translate x value?
Here is the code:

```
<svg>
 <g class="element" transform="translate(479, 247) scale(1)">...</g>
 <g class="element" transform="translate(874, 145) scale(1)">...</g>
 <g class="element" transform="translate(643, 356) scale(1)">...</g>
</svg>
```

As you can see x values of each element is 479,874, and 643.
I want to sort these 3 groups by that element's x value and append back to same SVG.

Expected Result:

```
<svg>
 <g class="element" transform="translate(874, 145) scale(1)">...</g>
 <g class="element" transform="translate(643, 356) scale(1)">...</g>
 <g class="element" transform="translate(479, 247) scale(1)">...</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in a slightly different way of doing it with lots of ES6 and functional ideas:

I modified the example a bit to show the order by the order in which the groups are painted on the SVG (in the order they appear in the DOM) by adding `<text/>` and `<rect/>` elements. So before it looks like this:

[image]

Then after it looks like this:

[image]

i.e. `<g class="element" transform="translate(479, 247) scale(1)">...</g>` is painted last because it is the last child of the `<svg/>` tag.

Code is below and codepen here: https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/PowLQZO

HTML:

```
<svg width=1000 height="1000">
 <g class="element" transform="translate(479, 247) scale(1)">
   <rect stroke="blue" fill="blue" x="0" y="0" height="200" width="450"/>
   <text>479</text>
  </g>
 <g class="element" transform="translate(874, 145) scale(1)">
   <rect stroke="red" fill="red" x="0" y="0" height="250" width="300"/>
   <text>874</text>
  </g>
 <g class="element" transform="translate(643, 356) scale(1)">
   <rect stroke="green" fill="green" x="0" y="0" height="200" width="350"/>
   <text>643</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

And Javascript:

```
const svg = document.querySelector("svg");
const groups = [...document.querySelectorAll("g")];

groups.map(child => {
   console.log(getValue(child))
});

function getValue(child){
  var transform = child.getAttribute("transform")
    .replace("translate(","")
    .replace(/\) scale.*/i,"");
  return transform.split(",")
    .map(el => parseInt(el));
}

groups.sort((a,b) => {
  return getValue(b)[0] - getValue(a)[0];
})

groups.forEach((el,index) => {
  svg.appendChild(el);
});
```

You could adapt the line `return getValue(b)[0] - getValue(a)[0];` to `a - b` and then it sorts ascending instead of descending. Also you can change the index from `(a)[0]` to `(a)[1]` to sort by y-translation instead.

Comment: Thank you so much @Alex L This is perfect! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery `sort` and some string parsing logic to retrieve your first parameter of `translate`:

```
function getValue(input){
    return parseInt(input.outerHTML.substring(input.outerHTML.indexOf('(') + 1, input.outerHTML.indexOf(',')));
}

$('svg g').sort(function(a, b) {
     return getValue(a) < getValue(b) ? 1 : -1;
}).appendTo('svg');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I got the x value of this as: var pos = $(this).position(); and i can use it as pos.top; //This gives x position value. Now trying to sort this. Will try your answer.