# Layering of Path Objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, svg

The project that I have been working on for the past month has many path objects that are beginning to overlap. My question is, is there a way to layer these objects? I want to be able to choose which object should be on top when it overlaps another object. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: svg elements are painted in the order in which they are in the DOM. (i.e the last elements are painted last and therefore painted on top). Check out my answer to a similar question and how you can re-order for elements to control paint order: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59909711/9792594

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jquery: How to sort SVG g element by translate filter value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59906589/jquery-how-to-sort-svg-g-element-by-translate-filter-value)